# Converting to chomsky normal form, eliminating epsilon

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory, context-free-language, chomsky-normal-form

I have a following CFG rule :

- S -> BSA | epsilon
- A -> abC | a | c
- B -> baC | b | epsilon
- C -> aCc | AB | epsilon

I am on the epsilon elimination stage of the algorithm, I have eliminated following eplsions C -> epsiolon, B -> epsilon and here is what i got so far :

> - S_0 -> S
> - **S -> BSA | SA | epsilon**
> - A -> abC | a | c| ab
> - B -> baC | b | ba
> - C -> aCc | AB | ac| A
>     Should I also eliminate S-> epsilon(shown in bold) since S is the original start variable?

Should I also copy the epsilon to S_0 at the unit rule stage of the algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I your first grammar, You can derive `epsilon` from `S`. So the empty word belong to the described language. Therefore you must have a `epsilon` in the second equivalent grammar.
Now in a normal form grammar, when there is a derivation `S -> epsilon`, then `S` can't appear on the right of a derivation. So the rule

```
S -> BSA | SA | epsilon
```

is not allowed is a Chomsky normal form. So you probably want something as

```
S_0 -> S | epsilon      // initial
S -> BA | A | BSA | SA
[...]
```